# How to create a dynamic select menu with woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, woocommerce, html-select

I would like to create a dynamic select menu.

The idea is that there are 2 select menus and the first one has two possible answers. The options within the second select menu will dynamically change immediately depending on what was chosen from the first.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I was thinking I would just do it using javaScript but I'm assuming there would be trouble saving the options with this.

Comment: Where exactly in woocommerce you want select menu? Frontend OR Backend?

Comment: On the front end, for users. The idea is the first select menu lets the user choose to pay by quantity or by price. And the second menu gets populated by 10 litres, 50 litres etc OR €50, €150 etc depending on what is selected from the first.